# iTunes Connect Application Loader Invalid Signature / Invalid Binary Error! HELP?

Tags: binary, app-store-connect, signature, application-loader

I have literally tried every single possible thing on every single post on this website and my app still gets rejected by the Invalid Binary Error. I am using a valid distribution certificate. Any idea? Using xCode 3.2.6 with ios 4.3. I have literally gone over the guide on the dev portal at least 20 times and I just need help!

Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.